# Handling keyboard interrupt in async zmq

Tags: python, zeromq, python-asyncio, pyzmq

I'm making a ZeroMQ server in `pyzmq` using `asyncio`. I'm trying to gracefully handle stopping the server, but there's very little documentation on the async module and there doesn't seem to be a simple way to handle stopping the current poll/await. Stopping the loop in the `.stop` method doesn't do much and won't actually exit.

```
import zmq
import zmq.asyncio
import asyncio

class ZMQHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = zmq.asyncio.ZMQEventLoop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.context = zmq.asyncio.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        self.socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5000')
        self.socket.linger = -1


    def start(self):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.listen())
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def stop(self):
        print('Stopping')
        self.loop.stop()

    async def listen(self):
        self.raw = await self.socket.recv()
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.listen())
```

Here's some example code that would start this:

```
daemon = ZMQHandler()

def signal_handler(num, frame):
    daemon.stop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

daemon.start()
```

How do I gracefully stop this when it's running? When I call `self.socket.close()`, I get the error `zmq.error.ZMQError: Socket operation on non-socket`, and if I call `self.context.destroy()` it basically complains that the sockets weren't terminated cleanly with `ETERM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a bug in the implementation of `pyzmq`. The bug was fixed and now calling `loop.stop()` works as intended.